# Control Does not get bind angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, widget

Am creating dynamic widgets using angular js, where the getting generated but there is an issue with the binding.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="pag-header"  >
    <a class="pull-right btn btn-primary" ng-click="addWidget()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add</a>
    <a class="pull-right btn btn-warning" ng-click="clear()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Clear</a>
    <!-- <h1 style="display: inline-block; width: 200px;">Dashboard</h1> -->


</div>
<div gridster="gridsterOptions">
    <ul>
         <li  ng-repeat="widget in dashboard.widgets"> 
            <div class="box"  ng-controller="CustomWidgetCtrl">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <h3>{{ widget.name }}</h3>
                    <div class="box-header-btns pull-right">
                        <a title="settings" ng-click="openSettings(widget)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a>
                        <a title="Remove widget" ng-click="remove(widget)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-content">
                </div>
            </div>
         </li>  
    </ul>
</div>
```

**App.JS**

```
var routerApp = angular.module('DuoDiginRt', ['ui.router']);
routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');

    $stateProvider          
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'view.html',
            controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
        })


});

routerApp.controller('DashboardCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout',
    function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.gridsterOptions = {
            margins: [20, 20],
            columns: 4,
            draggable: {
                handle: 'h3'
            }
        };
        $scope.dashboards = {

            '1': {
                id: '1',
                name: 'Home',
                widgets: [{
                    col: 0,
                    row: 0,
                    sizeY: 1,
                    sizeX: 1,
                    name: "Widget 1"
                }, {
                    col: 2,
                    row: 1,
                    sizeY: 1,
                    sizeX: 1,
                    name: "Widget 2"
                }]
            },
            '2': {
                id: '2',
                name: 'Other',
                widgets: [{
                    col: 1,
                    row: 1,
                    sizeY: 1,
                    sizeX: 2,
                    name: "Other Widget 1"
                }, {
                    col: 1,
                    row: 3,
                    sizeY: 1,
                    sizeX: 1,
                    name: "Other Widget 2"
                }]
            }
        };
        $scope.clear = function() {
            $scope.dashboard.widgets = [];
        };

        $scope.addWidget = function() {
            $scope.dashboard.widgets.push({
                name: "New Widget",
                sizeX: 1,
                sizeY: 1
            });
        };

         $scope.$watch('selectedDashboardId', function(newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                $scope.dashboard = $scope.dashboards[newVal];
            } else {
                $scope.dashboard = $scope.dashboards[1];
            }
         });

         // init dashboard
         $scope.selectedDashboardId = '1';

    }
])

routerApp.controller('CustomWidgetCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal',
    function($scope, $modal) {

        $scope.remove = function(widget) {
            $scope.dashboard.widgets.splice($scope.dashboard.widgets.indexOf(widget), 1);
        };

        $scope.openSettings = function(widget) {
            $modal.open({
                scope: $scope,
                templateUrl: 'widget_settings.html',
                controller: 'WidgetSettingsCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    widget: function() {
                        return widget;
                    }
                }
            });
        };

    }
])

routerApp.controller('WidgetSettingsCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$rootScope', '$modalInstance', 'widget',
    function($scope, $timeout, $rootScope, $modalInstance, widget) {
        $scope.widget = widget;

        $scope.form = {
            name: widget.name,
            sizeX: widget.sizeX,
            sizeY: widget.sizeY,
            col: widget.col,
            row: widget.row
        };

        $scope.sizeOptions = [{
            id: '1',
            name: '1'
        }, {
            id: '2',
            name: '2'
        }, {
            id: '3',
            name: '3'
        }, {
            id: '4',
            name: '4'
        }];

        $scope.dismiss = function() {
            $modalInstance.dismiss();
        };

        $scope.remove = function() {
            $scope.dashboard.widgets.splice($scope.dashboard.widgets.indexOf(widget), 1);
            $modalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.submit = function() {
            angular.extend(widget, $scope.form);

            $modalInstance.close(widget);
        };

    }
])

// helper code
routerApp.filter('object2Array', function() {
    return function(input) {
        var out = [];
        for (i in input) {
            out.push(input[i]);
        }
        return out;
    }
 });
```

**[image: output:]**

**Console:**

**Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal**

Comment: which is the modal module used in this case? have you properly included that modal js file

Comment: Can you please add your model service javascript code?

Comment: am not using any module, i have modified this https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster , took the dashboard.html  page and modified according to my need

Comment: am i asking a dumb question here?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap angular directive? if yes, inject ui.bootstrap on your module. I think you're injecting $modal (ui bootstrap provider) without adding the ui.bootstrap module.

Comment: While going through the source of the demo page, i found the reference to bootstrap angular UI module. you must include it in order to use $modal service.

Comment: @TechMa9iac where should i include that?

Comment: Yaa same concern here @ArunPJohny seems like an issue with `modalProvider` @Sajeetharan please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include both ui-bootstrap js files, and necessary module injection in the angular module declaration.

1. include the JS File.

   ```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Inject the ui-bootstrap module in the angular module declaration :

   ```
    var routerApp = angular.module('DuoDiginRt', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router']);
   ```

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module DuoDiginRt due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: I have defined the js file

Comment: Have you included the ui-bootstrap js file before your module declaration and after the angularjs js files. ?? Please share the updated code if possible..